# Can I avoid arrow keys and use any other shortcut that might be easy to access from home keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm using Dvorak layout, during programming or writing, it's difficult for me to move my hands from home keys to arrows key again and again, so can I create a shortcut such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> that'll alternative to left arrow key, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> alternative to right arrow?

Accessing to arrow key distract my focus from screen, and I'll have to look at the keyboard again and again, sometimes I even forget what was I about to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use 3rd layer symbols and assign arrows to letters `hjkl`.

1. Install `gnome-tweaks` tool
2. Inside gnome-tweaks, go to *Keyboard & Mouse* → *Additional Layout Options* → *Key to choose the 3rd level* and choose "Caps Look".
3. Then open your terminal and go to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`. There are all keyboard layouts stored on your computer.
4. Make a backup of your layout

   ```
   cp us us_old
   ```

   Modify file as `root`

   ```
   sudo nano us
   ```

Third values in arrays are your keys:

```
key <AC01> {[a,A,Home]};
key <AC02> {[s,S,BackSpace]};
key <AC03> {[d,D,Delete]};
key <AC04> {[f,F,End]};
key <AC05> {[g,G]};
key <AC06> {[h,H,Left]};
key <AC07> {[j,J,Down]};
key <AC08> {[k,K,Up]};
key <AC09> {[l,L,Right]};
```

Comment: Thanks dear, it worked! it just took me sometime, actually i have more than one layout so there were other keys too for other layout and some layout don't support 3rd level, so First i needed to change layout to one that supports dead keys, than find it´s keys and change them.

Comment: I also use 2 layouts: US and RU. I made changes for both. You can also change keys behaviours within layout files in symbols folder. As you can see the US layout doesnt have 3rd layer. (RU layout have just one 3rd layer symbol)

Comment: @PabloBianchi Thanks for formatting

Comment: Could you add more info? Do you have any source/reference links? In which section of the file should be added those lines? Works on Wayland? Is necessary to logout/in/restart?

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT : IT DOESN'T WORK

Don't *downvote*, I keep it here until someone could take that workaround to work with some kind of keybinding. I'll delete it when that time has come

---

Take a look at xdotool and its documentation.

```
 $ apt show xdotool
Package: xdotool
Version: 1:3.20160805.1-4
Priority: extra
Section: universe/x11
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Daniel Kahn Gillmor <dkg@fifthhorseman.net>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 125 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libx11-6, libxdo3 (>= 1:3.20150503.1)
Homepage: https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/
Task: ubuntu-budgie-desktop
Download-Size: 41.5 kB
APT-Sources: http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
Description: simulate (generate) X11 keyboard/mouse input events
 xdotool lets you programmatically (or manually) simulate keyboard
 input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc. It does this
 using X11's XTEST extension and other Xlib functions.
```

`sudo apt install xdotool`

You can then bind xdotool commands with these commands in `Setting > Keyboard shortcut`.
[image]

In your case, the xdotool patterns would be :

```
xdotool key Left
xdotool key Right
```

For up and down, it's... `Up` and `Down`

Comment: i've tested `xdotool key Left` in terminal and it outputs `^[[D`, mean it has installed properly, but if i create a shortcut key for this command and test it, it won't work, i tried changing shortcut key many time, still not works, i tested in VS Code, gedit and chrome, but still don't get my work done.

Comment: I see... it doesnt work for me neither... Since you use it for programming, maybe you can learn how to use Vim. It have good features, nature keybiding for arrows, and I think you can remap these keys... Waiting for others to get you a solution. Sorry

Comment: When you bind an `xdotool` command to a keyboard shortcut and that shortcut contains modifier keys, you should use the `--clearmodifiers` flag. Otherwise, the application will see e.g. [ctrl]+[shift]+[alt]+[leftarrow].

Comment: @danzel I just checked, it doesnt work either with the `--clearmodifers` flag :(

Answer (score 0):

To make things simple:

1. Go to your system-settings(in Ubuntu) and choose Devices (i think, 'Apparaten' in Dutch) in the leftside panel, or just type 'keyboard' in Search;
2. Select 'Keyboard & Mouse' and look for Keyboard 'Shortcuts' panel and make new or change old shortcuts on the fly.

Comment: there's no shortcut for arrows keys in Keyboard Shortcut section, i'll have to create one than i would need a command that'll manipulate the function of arrows key. and i'm looking for that one command.

Comment: man xdotool maybe... Modifier keys are sometimes enclosed in a left- and right-bracket: <'modkey'><'othermodkey'> but i'm not 100% always the case, i mean...

Comment: xdotool isn't working, it has proposed in previous answer.