# Down navigation key problem

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Superficially, it might appear that this question has been answered before. But please bear with me.

On starting my laptop, the <kbd>down</kbd> navigation key (down arrow) works fine. But on suspending and then resuming, the key stops working.

I'd like to either solve this problem or map the function to another key like the <kbd>right control</kbd> key. I'd appreciate greatly if you can point me to a GUI based solution.

Comment: Is it just the one key, or are there others?  One key would point to a hardware problem(dirt, bad connection).  This link might help with remapping key.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253059/can-i-avoid-arrow-keys-and-use-any-other-shortcut-that-might-be-easy-to-access-f

Comment: It's only down arrow key. I thought it was a mechanical problem or as you mentioned it could be dirt. I've removed the key and it seems fine. Also, on starting the laptop, the key works just fine. Only after suspending and resuming, the problem surfaces.

Comment: Think this problem would need an expert to figure out key problem.  Would be interesting to see if this happens with another keyboard(USB, wireless).  Would maybe see if keyboard or Ubuntu is problem.